# SQL shown no record after submit INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

When I submit an SQL query there is no record created in the database, but also no error message is displayed.

** Sorry for long code because I don't know where is the problem with the code and I also just have basic knowledge in programming.

I am using 2 different tables for query and insert:

```
<?php

    if(isset($send))
    {
        $today=date('Y-m-d');

        $fname=isset ($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
        $fname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $fname);

        $sql=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM kc54i_workforce_employees WHERE fname='$fname'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
        $namestaff=$row['lname'];

        $sql2 = "
        INSERT INTO `avenue`.`staff_movement` (`id`, `staff_no`, `department`, `name`, `status`, `category`, `dateStart`, `dateEng`)
        VALUES (NULL, '$fname','$department','$namestaff','$status','$category','$dateStart','$dateEnd');";

        if(@mysqli_query($con, $sql2))
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
            echo "alert('New record created successfully');\n";
            echo "window.navigate('add_move_test.php');";
            echo "</script>";
        }
        else
            echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . mysqli_error();
    }
    else  
?>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <form name="add_move_test.php" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return formCheck(this);">
    <table>
      <tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">Department</td>
        <td valign="top">
          <select name="department" onchange='this.form.submit();'>

            <?php $department=isset($_POST[ 'department']) ? $_POST[ 'department'] : ''; 
                  $department=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $department); ?>

            <option value="">-Select One-</option>
            <option value="7" <?php if ($department=="7" ) echo "selected";?>>Management</option>
            <option value="2" <?php if ($department=="2" ) echo "selected";?>>Administration</option>
            <option value="5" <?php if ($department=="5" ) echo "selected";?>>Human Resource</option>
            <option value="25" <?php if ($department=="25" ) echo "selected";?>>Business Development</option>
            <option value="12" <?php if ($department=="12" ) echo "selected";?>>Finance</option>
            <option value="19" <?php if ($department=="19" ) echo "selected";?>>Procurement</option>
            <option value="1" <?php if ($department=="1" ) echo "selected";?>>IT Support</option>
            <option value="6" <?php if ($department=="6" ) echo "selected";?>>Project</option>
            <option value="13" <?php if ($department=="13" ) echo "selected";?>>Project(Control)</option>
            <option value="10" <?php if ($department=="10" ) echo "selected";?>>Project(Management)</option>
            <option value="8" <?php if ($department=="8" ) echo "selected";?>>Project(Transportation)</option>
            <option value="24" <?php if ($department=="24" ) echo "selected";?>>Construction</option>
            <option value="16" <?php if ($department=="16" ) echo "selected";?>>Construction(Management)</option>
            <option value="4" <?php if ($department=="4" ) echo "selected";?>>Construction(Planning & Cost Estimation)</option>
            <option value="18" <?php if ($department=="18" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering</option>
            <option value="15" <?php if ($department=="15" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Civil)</option>
            <option value="14" <?php if ($department=="14" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Fire & Gas)</option>
            <option value="23" <?php if ($department=="23" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Electrical)</option>
            <option value="22" <?php if ($department=="22" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Instrument)</option>
            <option value="3" <?php if ($department=="3" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Mechanical)</option>
            <option value="9" <?php if ($department=="9" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Layout & Piping)</option>
            <option value="20" <?php if ($department=="20" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Process)</option>
            <option value="17" <?php if ($department=="17" ) echo "selected";?>>HSSE</option>
            <option value="11" <?php if ($department=="11" ) echo "selected";?>>Quality(QA/QC)</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">Name</td>
        <td valign="top">
          <select name="fname">
            <option selected>-Select Name-</option>

            <?php $sql="select * from kc54i_workforce_employees where department='$department' ORDER BY lname ASC" ; 
                  $results=mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
                  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {                        $department=$row[ 'department']; 
                  $name=$row[ 'lname']; $fname=$row['fname']; ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $fname;?>">
                           <?php echo $name;?>
            </option>
            <?php 
             } 
            ?>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">Category</td>
        <td valign="top">
          <select name="category">
            <?php $category=i sset($_POST[ 'category']) ? $_POST[ 'category'] : ''; $category=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $category); ?>
            <option value="">-Select One-</option>
            <option value="office" <?php if ($category=="office" ) echo "selected";?>>Office</option>
            <option value="site" <?php if ($category=="site" ) echo "selected";?>>Site</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">Date Start</td>
        <td valign="top">
          <script>
            DateInput('dateStart', true)
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">Date End</td>
        <td valign="top">
          <script>
            DateInput('dateEnd', true)
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">Status</td>
        <td valign="top">
          <input name="status" type="text" id="status" size="50" maxlength="50">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center" valign="middle">
        <td colspan="2">
          <input name="send" type="submit" id="send" value="Send">
          <input name="clear" type="reset" id="clear" value="Clear">
          <input type="button" name="back" value="Back" onClick="javascript:history.back();">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd recommend doing a couple of things to debug your code. Use `print_r($_POST)` to print all of the data that was sent by the form. Also, I'd use `echo  $sql2` to print out the second query and run it in MySQL Workbench (or some program that connects directly to the database) to see if the query works there. If it doesn't work there, it's easier to change and debug within MySQL Workbench (or the like). Also, you may want to do the same with the query that returns the last name.

Comment: Never ever use `@` to suppress error / warning during debug phase.

Comment: First check is your error reporting is on or not!

Comment: And where is your connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is space in between `isset` function all things are already there,I just run it because I don't have table structure of yours,

```
 <html>
    <body>
      <form name="add_move_test.php" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return formCheck(this);">
        <table>
          <tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">Department</td>
            <td valign="top">
              <select name="department" onchange='this.form.submit();'>

                <?php 
                $department=isset($_POST[ 'department']) ? $_POST[ 'department'] : ''; 
                $department=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $department); ?>

                <option value="">-Select One-</option>
                <option value="7" <?php if ($department=="7" ) echo "selected";?>>Management</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if ($department=="2" ) echo "selected";?>>Administration</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if ($department=="5" ) echo "selected";?>>Human Resource</option>
                <option value="25" <?php if ($department=="25" ) echo "selected";?>>Business Development</option>
                <option value="12" <?php if ($department=="12" ) echo "selected";?>>Finance</option>
                <option value="19" <?php if ($department=="19" ) echo "selected";?>>Procurement</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if ($department=="1" ) echo "selected";?>>IT Support</option>
                <option value="6" <?php if ($department=="6" ) echo "selected";?>>Project</option>
                <option value="13" <?php if ($department=="13" ) echo "selected";?>>Project(Control)</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if ($department=="10" ) echo "selected";?>>Project(Management)</option>
                <option value="8" <?php if ($department=="8" ) echo "selected";?>>Project(Transportation)</option>
                <option value="24" <?php if ($department=="24" ) echo "selected";?>>Construction</option>
                <option value="16" <?php if ($department=="16" ) echo "selected";?>>Construction(Management)</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if ($department=="4" ) echo "selected";?>>Construction(Planning & Cost Estimation)</option>
                <option value="18" <?php if ($department=="18" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering</option>
                <option value="15" <?php if ($department=="15" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Civil)</option>
                <option value="14" <?php if ($department=="14" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Fire & Gas)</option>
                <option value="23" <?php if ($department=="23" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Electrical)</option>
                <option value="22" <?php if ($department=="22" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Instrument)</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if ($department=="3" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Mechanical)</option>
                <option value="9" <?php if ($department=="9" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Layout & Piping)</option>
                <option value="20" <?php if ($department=="20" ) echo "selected";?>>Engineering(Process)</option>
                <option value="17" <?php if ($department=="17" ) echo "selected";?>>HSSE</option>
                <option value="11" <?php if ($department=="11" ) echo "selected";?>>Quality(QA/QC)</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">Name</td>
            <td valign="top">
              <select name="fname">
                <option selected>-Select Name-</option>

                <?php $sql="select * from kc54i_workforce_employees where department='$department' ORDER BY lname ASC" ; 
                      $results=mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
                      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                          $department=$row[ 'department']; 
                      $name=$row[ 'lname']; $fname=$row['fname']; ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $fname;?>">
                               <?php echo $name;?>
                </option>
                <?php 
                 } 
                ?>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">Category</td>
            <td valign="top">
              <select name="category">
                <?php $category=isset($_POST[ 'category']) ? $_POST[ 'category'] : ''; $category=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $category); ?>
                <option value="">-Select One-</option>
                <option value="office" <?php if ($category=="office" ) echo "selected";?>>Office</option>
                <option value="site" <?php if ($category=="site" ) echo "selected";?>>Site</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">Date Start</td>
            <td valign="top">
              <script>
                DateInput('dateStart', true)
              </script>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">Date End</td>
            <td valign="top">
              <script>
                DateInput('dateEnd', true)
              </script>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">Status</td>
            <td valign="top">
              <input name="status" type="text" id="status" size="50" maxlength="50">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td colspan="2">
              <input name="send" type="submit" id="send" value="Send">
              <input name="clear" type="reset" id="clear" value="Clear">
              <input type="button" name="back" value="Back" onClick="javascript:history.back();">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```